# Mathjax/LaTex code for placing tilde beneath a variable

Tags: math-mode, mathjax

I know that `\tilde{x}` will produce [image] but how do I make it that `\tilde` will be below [image] ?

Comment: For mathjax, I  don't know. For LaTeX, you can load the `accents` package, and use `\underaccent{tilde}{x}`.

Comment: `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `\( \underset{\sim}{x} \)` would work. However, it would be overkill to usepackage `amsmath` _just_ for this effect.